# enthought canopy package manager "no arguments"

Tags: enthought, canopy

I have been using Enthought Canopy Distribution (Academic License) for the last few weeks. I have also used the Package Manager to install packages.

But now today when I tried to install Scikit learn it showed the following error message "Takes no argument 1 given". Infact this problem is there even if I try to install other packages. I also tried to upgrade a few packages, but those too showed the same error.

Have I changed some setting by mistake or is it an issue[image] with the software?

Comment: Platform? (e.g. Win 7 - 64-bit)

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in both the Canopy GUI and on the command line (epkg) on OS X 10.8 with the 32-bit version. This is part of the reply I got from the Enthought support team:

> This looks like a familiar bug which should have been fixed.
>
> Could you please update to 1.0.1.1191, and if the problem still occurs, then submit this as a bug report from the Canopy Help menu so we can gather more system information?

Only problem is, I am running 1.0.1.1190, and Help/Software Updates... claims there is no newer version available. I informed support of this, and I will report back as soon as I have more information on or a solution for this problem.

**Update**

Planning do document the exact error message, I just went back to the command line and invoked epkg, which suddenly *did* work:

> $ enpkg
>
> Enstaller is out of date.  Update? ([y]/n) y
>
> enstaller-4.6.1-2.egg
>   [fetching]    264 KB
>   [.................................................................]
>
> enstaller-4.6.1-2.egg
>   [installing]    755 KB
>   [.................................................................]
>
> Enstaller has been updated. Please re-run your previous command.

I can now successfully install and update packages via enpkg or the Canopy GUI.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the version 1.0.1.1191 was a red herring (an internal build number)